# Why does Jira want localId elements when doing a bulk create issue in the API?

Tags: json, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm creating taskLists in the issues, and from the json schema I get that localIds are required. That seems weird, as ids are not required (as long as I don't want to reference them). What are the technical reasons for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. So it turns out Jira does not fully support Atlassian Document Format. No tasklists at all.

Comment: You're right. Jira doesn't support Task Lists inside the Description or Comments field.

This is mostly because a mechanism for assigning a list of tasks to people is already provided via Sub-tasks, which are vastly more feature rich than Task Lists in Confluence using ADF.

Comment: Thank you @DavidBakkers, I ended up creating sub-tasks indeed.